# Escaping Shell echos

Tags: php, shell, escaping, command, exec

I tried to do my research, there is just an abundance of ways to call shell commands, and even more ways to strip harmful characters that I am coming to stackoverflow for an expert's best recommendation.

I was hoping to find something like I've seen other languages so where sending arguments to a command are actually passed through a function, like:

do_command("ls", "-l", $Directory);

and it will take care of anything harmful in the $Directory variable for you. I haven't quite found this with PHP.

This is the code I am working with:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $AdminEmail = "random_email@gmail.com";
    $CatalogEmails = array("");
    $QuoteEmails = array("");
    $PartsEmails = array("");

    $Subject = $_SESSION['Email_Subject'];
    $Body = $_SESSION['Email_Body'];
    $Headers = $_SESSION['Email_Headers'];
    $Type = $_SESSION['Type'];

    msmtp($AdminEmail, $Subject, $Body, $Headers, "meyers");

    if ($Type == "Catalog") {
        foreach ($CatalogEmails as $AdditionalEmail) {
            msmtp($AdditionalEmail, $Subject, $Body, $Headers, "meyers");
        }
    } else if ($Type == "Quote") {
        foreach ($QuoteEmails as $AdditionalEmail) {
            msmtp($AdditionalEmail, $Subject, $Body, $Headers, "meyers");
        }
    } else if ($Type == "Parts") {
        foreach ($PartsEmails as $AdditionalEmail) {
            msmtp($AdditionalEmail, $Subject, $Body, $Headers, "meyers");
        }
    }

    function msmtp($To, $Subject, $Body, $Headers, $Account) {
        $Email = "To: $To\nSubject: $Subject\n$Headers\n\n$Body\n";
        exec("echo \"$Email\" | msmtp --account=$Account $To");
    }

    session_destroy();
?>
```

I know there is a built-in PHP mail function that pretty much would take care of this, but I am running multiple SMTP servers and the `msmtp` is a program I use that sends emails based on the "account" the email will be sent under. In this case it will be the "meyers" account.

All the sessions variables contain HTML (`<br>`'s `<b>`'s, etc) with some `$_POST` vars in there as well. I use PHP 5.3 so no magic quotes.

I know using an echo is a horrid way, which is why I am coming to stackoverflow. My goal here is that the email will go through despite any kind of crazy character they throw at me. I know the shell/bash is picky-- I assume it's much more than just escaping double quotes.

I tried using `escapeshellcmd`  `escapeshellarg` and `htmlentities`, they all escape too much or mess up the HTML in the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the email content to a file, then redirect the file content as the input to the msmtp command.

```
file_put_contents($tempfile,$Email);
exec("msmtp --account=$Account $To < $tempfile");
```

Answer (score 1):

Is PHP using the Bourne shell (sh) or Bash? In either case, it might be better if you use `printf`:

```
exec("printf '%s' '$Email' | msmtp --account=$Account $To");
```

If you are using Bash, you can try the quoting feature of its `printf`:

```
exec("printf '%q' '$Email' | msmtp --account=$Account $To");
```

Comment: This seems to be over quoting, making the `\n` become `\\n` and etc.

Comment: @BHare: What about the first one?